# A differential equation that looks easy

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x+y}$$
Now seeing this I thought I should square both sides, because that seemed like the only thing I could so besides move around the $dy$ or $dx$, doing so I get
$$\frac{(dy)^2}{(dx)^2}=x+y$$
Now moving the terms to their respective sides and integrating
$$\int\frac{dx^2}{x}=\int\frac{dy^2}{y}$$
$$\ln(x)+c=\ln(y)$$
$$y=x+c$$
Am I correct in my arithmatic or do I still need to integrate again because the terms were squared?

Comment: That is an example of how not to do it.

Comment: There are multiple mistakes. For starter, how do you go from your squared equation to your integrals?

Comment: @AlainRemillard actually upon further inspection it seems none of this computation is justified.

Comment: @CyclotimicField I totally agree with you.

Comment: You can't just pretend $\frac{dx^2}{x}$ is synonymous with $\frac{dx}{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, none of your steps make sense. The usual way to treat an equation like this is the substitution $u=x+y$. Then $u'=1+y'$ and so the equation becomes $$u'=1+u^{1/2}.$$ This is separable, so dividing and integrating you get $$2\sqrt u-\log(1+\sqrt{u})=x+c. $$ Putting $u=x+y$ back, we get an equation expressing $y$ implicitly in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $u^2=x+y$, then $2uu'=1+y'$ or $y'=2uu'-1$. Now the equations turns to
$$2uu'-1=u\implies\\
\frac{2u}{u+1}u'=1$$
This is a seperable function and the solution is
$$2u-2\ln(u+1)=x+c$$
Now substitude $u=\sqrt{x+y}$.

Comment: Nice.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mjw Your kindness${}{}{}$

Comment: why did you replace the $y'$ in the $2^{nd}$ line with $u$?

Comment: I replaced $y'$ with $2uu'-1$ and $\sqrt{x+y}$ with $u$ to make the problem solvable